# Django REST Framework structure with homemade ERP client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am about to create a new REST API where I have to implement an ERP API within, more of the Django APPS will have to have access to the ERP API. my question is, where to put the "homemade" ERP API wrapper

```
project
 - project
  - config
  - users
  - customers
  - libs / erp ???
 requirements.txt
```

and from the customers app then import from libs /erp

what is best practice here?

Comment: Why not a separate `erp` app within you project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be creating a Separate App for the ERP API as it would be the most suited Approach!
Now Comming to the Fact, "more of the Django APPS will have to have access to the ERP API"
. You can use requests library to interact with it via URL's if you are depending on its Response in another App, Otherwise you can import it with

```
import erp_api as ERPAPI
```

and use it Further.

You can also call the Views Directly in Django!